# Monetory fields not taking 0 value instead its reverting to previous value in odoo 13.0 ver

Tags: python, field, odoo-13

I have some custom modules developed from scratch in that Monetory fields are not taking 0 value instead its reverting to previous value.
installation : odoo 13.0 exe installation

installed on : 13.0.20200412

Example :
In form view xxx_monetory : 5000 --> 0 when I click on save button the previous value i.e 5000 is reverting back to that field.
This is happening only in custom modules not in standard modules like CRM, Sales etc.
Please help me out on this.

Field declaration :

In .py file

company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', store=True, copy=False, string="Company", default=lambda self: self.env.user.company_id.id)
currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', string="Currency", related='company_id.currency_id', default=lambda self: self.env.user.company_id.currency_id.id)
fee = fields.Monetary(string="Fee")

In .xml file

<name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>
<name="fee"/>

Answer (score 0):

You should use `fields.Integer` or `fields.Float` instead of `fields.Monetary` to represent numbers in Odoo.

In your view:

```
<field name="currency_id" invisible="1" />
<field name="fee" widget="monetary" options="{'currency_field': 'currency_id'}" />
```

Comment: Yes, I can use fields.Float like as you mentioned. But Client want reason behind this behavior Becasue same Monetory fields are taking 0 values in standard modules but in custom modules it's not. 
I asked them to share their odoo environment for reproducing the issue. In their environment its reproducing but in my (local) environment (Source installation) it's not showing any issues.
I suggested them to update environment but they are not ready because as it's not showing any issues in standard modules, why only in custom modules?? Even I don't find any valid reason to tell that

Comment: It would be very helpful if I could get reason for this behavior.

Comment: Could you update your question with your code? Provided examples aren't clear and do not meets odoo views syntax